# Why do we need object Serialization in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization

Do we always need to serialize the object in c++ if we want to persist that object or to transfer over network, or in special cases only.

For instance if I have an object of the class

```
class Test
{
int a;
char b;
float c;
};
```

i.e. it contains only primitive types do I need to serialize it?

Comment: That really depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: There's a difference between "what works", and in this example no serialisation is needed, and "what you should do". Realistically, if you're sending data anywhere (even to disk), it's best to serialise.

Comment: You need to serialize the object if you need to serialize the object, and persisting it or sending it over the network are examples of that. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: When thinking about this problem (without the support of specialized libraries) you should be thinking more at the byte level, e.g. what is the in memory representation of a struct (alignment, padding, endianness), how it will be represented at the disk/network layer, and hardware differences. Your question also does not mention how you intend to "transfer" or "persist" an object without serializing it first - explaining your ideas about that might help put this question into perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you do with the persisted/transferred objects.

In some special case, when you only ever read back the objects using the same version of the program on the same, or identical, machine, you may simply copy the objects to a character stream bit by bit.

But in general yes, you do need to serialize. If built with different options, the class may have different amounts of padding, making the binary formats incompatible between them. Different CPU architechtures have different endianness and multi-byte values like `int` and `float` must be converted between them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to serialize. When sending information from A to B it always transforms to a bytearray. Side B needs to know how to "deserialize" the bytearray.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of object and on the type of host.

**The object should be trivially copyable** (see [std::is_trivially_copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable%20%22is_trivially_copyable%22))). Such objects must not have non-trivial copy/move constructors or non-trivial assignment operators and they need a trivial destructor. All scalar types and structs of scalar types are trivially copyable for example. std::string is not.

Both instances of the application have to use the same **packing alignment for structures** (see #pragma pack for example).

**The network host have to use the same byte order**. If one host uses Big-endian and the other one uses Little-endian the biggest unit of information that can be transferred without special attention is a byte (uint8_t for example). Even a simple int cannot be moved between two machines with different endianess (what's 0x11223344 for one machine is 0x44332211 for the other)